# android studio 2.0 showing log4j Warning when launch in terminal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, log4j, android-studio-2.0

I was kind curious about the warning when I start android studio 2.0 and always got this message in my terminal:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have visited the suggested [site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig) and from what I understand the configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml are missing so I tried to find the file in the root directory and I could not found them this is the screenshot :
 
[image]

My Questions are :

1. How to resolve this issue so I will not see the warning message again?
2. Could somebody explain what is log4j for in android studio?

any help and useful information would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's no critical error. Log4j is a logging framework to log output. If you don't have a configuration file, nothing is logged. You can add them manually if you want.

Comment: do you know how to hide the warning message?